# Filling cell from NSDictionary keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary in my class ItemStore:

```
        NSArray *operatorUS = @[@"AT&T", @"Verizion"];
        NSArray *operatorRU = @[@"MTS", @"Megafon"];
        NSArray *operatorFR = @[@"Orange", @"SFR"];
        NSArray *operatorAE = @[@"Etisalat", @"Du"];
        self = [super init];
            _privateItems = @{@"USA":operatorUS, @"Russia":operatorRU, @"France":operatorFR, @"UAE":operatorAE};
```

and the method

```
-(NSArray *)allItems
    {
        return [self.privateItems allKeys];
    }
```

in ViewController I do this:

```
NSArray *items = [[MSTItemStore sharedStore] allItems];
MSTItem *item = items[indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",item];

return cell;
```

And

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MSTProviderViewController *providerViewController = [[MSTProviderViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:providerViewController animated:YES];
}
```

But in my TableView, when I click at cell it sometimes pushes the providerViewController, but sometimes it doesn't. What is the problem?

Comment: Your question's title has nothing to do with what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Push your view controller on

```
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

instead of

```
tableView:didDeselectrowAtIndexPath:
```

unless you have a different reason (which I can't think of).

Comment: Nitpick - word your answer as an answer and not as a question.

Comment: Most common mistake ever!

Comment: Thanks! Didn't even notice that, maybe it's really 5 days of work :)